# C# Get json From MySQLDatabase With PHP

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I just started C#. I want to exchange data from my remote server. I couldn't find any code that would work for me. It would be great if you could help with code snippets. Some of my sample code is below.

My PHP Code;

```
<?php
include 'Connect.php';
$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    
    if($tag == 'CheckUser') {
        
        $UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
        $Password = $_POST["Password"];
        
        try {
            $Check = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName=? AND Password=?";
            $query = $con->prepare($Check);
            $query->execute(array($UserName, $Password));
            $Dataa= $query->rowCount();
            if($Dataa> 0) {
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "User Found";
            }
            else {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "User Not Found";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "You do not have transaction authorization";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

How can I get the results of **"success"** and **"message"** in C#? Could you please suggest a sample code snippet?

Comment: have you searched for `rest api c# php`

Comment: @nbk no I have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read JSON responses from your web endpoint using the Newtonsoft.Json package that you can get from Nuget. Add it to your package and use it like this:

```
// Convert the string response from your web request to an object, in this case, "WebResponseDto".
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebResponseDto>(responseString);
```

Then, you can check the object like this.

```
 if (resp.Success == 1) { // Your code here }
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/